# Regular expression for a specific number sequence (EMŠO - Slovenia)

Tags: javascript, regex, expression

i need to make an irregular expression, which i intend to use for validating form data. The input is a very specific type of number (EMŠO), which is a unique identifier of a person in Slovenia.

```
The expression should be defined as:
- 1. position: only digits 0, 1, 2, 3
- 2. position: any digit
- 3. position: only digits 0 and 1
- 4. position: any digit
- 5., 6. and 7. position: any digit
- 8. position: must be a 5
- 9. position: must be a 0
- 10. position: only digits 0 and 5
- 11., 12. and 13. position: any digit
```

Any help would be very welcome.

Comment: What problem are you having? This seems really simple. You use `[xyz]` to match any of the characters `x`, `y`, or `z`, and use `\d` to match any digit.

Comment: I',m just very noob at this...i used to to validation with spliting string and looking by characters...but i wan't to do it like this

Comment: SO is not a tutoring service, you have to do your own research. Read the tutorial at www.regular-expression.info.

Comment: Your specification doesn't really match the specification [described by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_Master_Citizen_Number). For one thing it will match invalid dates (`3919017`). It will also reject EMŠOs for citizens born outside of Slovenia ("political region" other than `50`—although perhaps foreign-born citizens get new EMŠOs when they become citizens?).

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. If you want to learn regex try [this](https://regexone.com/) tutorial. It's actually pretty fun.

```
[0,1,2,3]\d[0,1]\d{4}50[0,5]\d{3}
```

Comment: i see it works :) thank you but is it possible to make it like a little longer and thus easier to understand :)

Comment: What part do you find confusing? I know regex can be intimidating at first.

Comment: okk as i was typing this comment now to reply i figured it out :D never mind :) thank you again

Comment: Glad I could help! Please accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: What about this one:

Comment: 1. part: at least one lowercase letter OR at least one uppercase letter, 2. part: @, 3. part: same as part 1